# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT on Express server

Tags: node.js, express, http, promise, http-headers

I'm fairly new to Node.js and Express, so my knowledge of asynchronous programming is lacking. I'm currently trying to create a simple registry endpoint for an app on my Express server but I keep running into this error: ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. I have checked everywhere in my code and made sure only to execute the res.send() function once.

Here's a shortened snippet of what I have:

```
app.post('/register', (req, res, done) => {
    register(req, res).then((response) => {
        res.send({
            success: response.success,
            message: response.message
        });
        
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
    done();
});


function register(req, res) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (req.body.password != req.body.confirmPassword) {
            resolve({
                success: false,
                message: "Passwords need to match."
            });
        }
        else {
            userExists(req, res).then((response) => {
                resolve(response);
            }).catch((error) => {
                reject({
                    success: false,
                    message: error.message
                });
            });
        }
    });
}


function userExists(req, res) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        findUser(req.body.username).then((response) => {
            if (response.length > 0) {
                resolve(true);
            }
            else {
                resolve(false);
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            reject(new Error(error.message));
        });
    });
}

function findUser(username) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE USERNAME=?", username, function(error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                reject(new Error(error.message));
            }
            else {
                resolve(results);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I have read that the error usually occurs because the res.send() function was executed more than once. I originally had multiple res.send() commands, but they were separated by if/else control structures and more than one would not have been executed. Still, I tried consolidating all these statements by creating a register() function that would return a resolved Promise with all the data I need to send, but this has not worked either.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Remove `done();`

Comment: @hoangdv that worked perfectly! such a simple fix. May I ask why the done() function would cause this error?

Comment: In general, the third parameter name should be `next` in stead of `done`. When you call `done()` it means go to next handler, but you dont need to go to the next, just `res.send` is enough.